# CMake Error when using ros_build in Indigo for code earlier used in Groovy

Tags: catkin, ros-package-path, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I have upgraded a system from Ubuntu 12.04 and Groovy to 14.04 and Indigo.
The system was earlier based on packages build with `ros_build.` I now switched to `catkin` for the standard packaes. However, there are two packages that are created for the specific system with ros_build. To make it easy, I used the tutorial to [Developing rosbuild packages on top of groovy](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin#rosbuild_workspace_on_top_of_catkin_workspace) and made a `rosbuild_ws` so that I have a `~/rosbuild_ws` and a `~/catkin_ws`. Building the first package went quite smoothly, but the other gave some errors. The package depends on some [libraries](http://www.fotonic.com/product/fotonic-e-serie-16w/fz-linux-api_x64/) that are placed in the same directory. These libraries are just added and not compiled on my computer.

Question: What do need to change to compile this code without errors?

The structure:

```
~/rosbuild_ws
     /the-other-pkg
    /fotonic
        /bin
        /build
        /CMakeFiles
        /include
        /launch
        /lib
        /src
        /test    
        /fz-linux-api        ---this directory contains libraries from Fotonic 
       CMakeLists.txt
       mainpage.dox
       Makefile
       manifest.xml
```

When I run `ros_make fotonic` i get the following error in the terminal window:

```
 [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/indigo/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/indigo/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:38 (if):
    if given arguments:
  
      "CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P" "EQUALS" "4"
  
    Unknown arguments specified
    
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "/home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package fotonic written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/klas/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20160720-030402/fotonic/build_output.log
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< fotonic [FAIL] [ 2.79 seconds ]
```

Row 36-44 in CMakeList.txt contains:

```
36    SET (FOTONIC_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/fz-linux-api/include CACHE PATH "fotonic_include dir")
    
38    if( CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUALS 4 )
39      SET (FOTONIC_LIBRARY_DIRS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/fz-linux-api/lib)
    
41    else( CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUALS 4 )
42      SET (FOTONIC_LIBRARY_DIRS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/fz-linux-api/lib64)
    
44    endif( CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUALS 4 )
```

And the CMakeError.log tells the following:

```
Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec3611313723/fast"
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3611313723.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3611313723.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3611313723.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3611313723.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec3611313723
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3611313723.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3611313723.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec3611313723 -rdynamic 
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3611313723.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[2]: *** [cmTryCompileExec3611313723] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec3611313723/fast] Error 2

File /home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec3516905749/fast"
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3516905749.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3516905749.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3516905749.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3516905749.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec3516905749
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3516905749.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3516905749.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec3516905749 -rdynamic -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [cmTryCompileExec3516905749] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec3516905749/fast] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
```

The `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is set to:
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/klas/catkin_ws/src:/home/klas/rosbuild_ws/fotonic:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239885/cmake-error-when-using-ros_build-in-indigo-for-code-earlier-used-in-groovy/) by [perfectspeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/27103/perfectspeed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The CMake log looks like normal operation of cmake; trying several different sets of flags and options to determine if the pthreads library is available or not.

The real issue here seems to be your equality operator; it looks like the semantics of `EQUALS` has changed in newer versions of cmake.

According the to the [cmake documentation for `IF`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aif), it looks like you should use `EQUAL` or `STREQUAL`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [perfectspeed](https://answers.ros.org/users/27103/perfectspeed/) on 2016-07-20**:
Thanks, ahendrix!
I changed it from `EQUALS` to `EQUAL` and it worked! :D

Afterwards I realize that I should have noticed this. The editor didn't mark the expression correctly, but I was focusing on the wrong part of the expression. Thanks again!